# ¿Como puedo hacer un WHILE y que respete los datos dentro?

Tags: php, mysql, while

Esto lo hice en una primera versión, pero se me hace raro que no funcione en la segunda versión haber si me pueden ayudar a encontrar el error.

El problema es que en la primera versión al dar clic en un botón insertado dentro del mismo WHILE respeta los datos jalados del mismo perfil.

Versión 1

```
<div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
                <!-- Intento de impresion FUNCIONANDO -->
                <?php
                  //include("conexion.php");
                  // $sql = "SELECT Pro.idpropietarios, Pro.p_nombres, Pro.p_tel, Pro.p_callenumero, Pro.p_colonia, Pro.ciudad, Pro.p_estado, Mas.m_nombre, Mas.m_nac, Mas.m_rasgos, Mas.m_enfermedades, Mas.m_habitos, Mas.id_mascotas, Mas.id_prop FROM propietarios Pro, mascotas Mas WHERE p_email = '$iduser'";
                  $sql = "SELECT Pro.idpropietarios, Pro.p_nombres, Pro.p_tel, Pro.p_callenumero, Pro.p_colonia, Pro.ciudad, Pro.p_estado, Mas.m_nombre, Mas.m_nac, Mas.m_rasgos, Mas.m_enfermedades, Mas.m_habitos, Mas.id_mascotas, Mas.id_prop, Mas.m_img, year(now()) - year(m_nac) as Edad, m_estado, m_enadopcion FROM mascotas Mas join propietarios Pro on  Mas.id_prop=Pro.idpropietarios  WHERE p_email = '$iduser'";
                  $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
                  while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                    $btn_extravio_estilo   = $row['m_estado'] != "Extraviado" ? "secondary" : "danger";
                    $btn_extravio_texto    = $row['m_estado'] != "Extraviado" ? "Reportar Extravio" : "Reportar Encontrado";
                    $val_extravio          = $row['m_estado'] == "Extraviado" ? "En casa" : "Extraviado";
                    $btn_enadopcion_estilo = $row['m_enadopcion'] == 0 ? "secondary" : "danger";
                    $val_enadopcion        = $row['m_enadopcion'] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    echo '
                    <div class="post">
                  <div class="user-block">
                    <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="img/'.$row['m_img'].'" alt="user image">
                    <span class="username">
                      <a href="perfil.php?id='.$row['id_mascotas'].'" style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$row['m_nombre'].' COD KR'.$row['id_mascotas'].'</a>
                      <a href="#" class="float-right btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="description">Actualización - 7:30 PM 12/12/2021</span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.user-block -->
                  <p class="float-right"><img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=https://rumam.com.mx/registro/perfil.php?id='.$row['id_mascotas'].'&chld=H" style="width=300px !important;"></p>
                  <p><b>Edad:</b> '.$row['Edad'].' Años</p>
                  <p><b>Raza:</b> Mixta</p>
                  <p><b>Color</b> '.$row['m_rasgos'].'</p>
                  <b>Enfermedades:</b>
                  <p>
                    '.$row['m_enfermedades'].'
                  </p>
                  <b>Malos habitos:</b>
                  <p>
                    '.$row['m_habitos'].'
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm mr-2"><i class="fas fa-share mr-1"></i> <button type="submit" name="reportarm" class="btn btn-'.$btn_extravio_estilo.'" onclick="reporta_extravio('.$row['id_mascotas'].',\''.$val_extravio.'\')">'.$btn_extravio_texto.'</button></a>
                    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#admascota"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editar('.$row['id_mascotas'].',\''.$row['m_nombre'].'\',\''.$row['m_rasgos'].'\',\''.$row['m_enfermedades'].'\',\''.$row['m_habitos'].'\')">Actualizar Datos</button></a>
                    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm mr-2"><button type="submit" name="adopcionm" class="btn btn-'.$btn_enadopcion_estilo.'" onclick="enadopcion('.$row['id_mascotas'].',\''.$val_enadopcion.'\')">En Adopción</button></a>
                    <span class="float-right">
                      <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
                        <i class="mr-1"></i>
                      </a>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                    ';
                  }
                 ?>   
                <!-- fin del intento -->
              </div>
```

En la version 2

```
 <?php 
      // consulta a la base de mascotas

      // sigue sin lograrse pero no da error, pero no muestra datos ver como se pude muestra o usar el atributo WHILE

      include "config/config.php";

      $usuario = $_SESSION['username'];
      
      $sqlMascotas = "SELECT * FROM mascotas m INNER JOIN propietarios p ON p.pemail = '$usuario' AND p.idpropietarios = m.idpropietario";
      $resultadoMascotas = $conexion->query($sqlMascotas);
      while ($row2 = $resultadoMascotas->fetch_assoc()){

       
      
      echo '<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <p class="mb-1 pt-2 text-bold">Codigo: KR'.$row2['idmascota'].'</p>
                <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">'.$row2['mnombre'].'</h5>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Fecha de Nacimiento: </strong> '.$row2['mnacimiento'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Salud: </strong>'.$row2['msalud'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Habitos: </strong>'.$row2['mhabitos'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Descripcion: </strong>'.$row2['mdescripcion'].'</p>
                <button class="btn-danger btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalExtravio">Reportar Extraviado</button>
                <button class="btn-success btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalAdopcion">Dar en Adopción</button>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 ms-auto text-center mt-5 mt-lg-0">
              <div class="bg-gradient-primary border-radius-lg h-100">
                <img src="v1/assets/img/shapes/waves-white.svg" class="position-absolute h-100 w-50 top-0 d-lg-block d-none" alt="waves">
                <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <img class="h-100 w-75 position-relative z-index-2 pt-4" src="images/'.$row2['mimagen'].'" alt="rocket">
                </div>
                
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 ms-auto text-center mt-5 mt-lg-0">
              <div class="bg-gradient-primary border-radius-lg h-100">
                <img src="v1/assets/img/shapes/waves-white.svg" class="position-absolute h-100 w-50 top-0 d-lg-block d-none" alt="waves">
                <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <img class="w-60 position-relative z-index-2 pt-4" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=https://rumam.com.mx/app/perfil.php?id='.$row2['idmascota'].'&chld=H" style="width=300px !important;"" alt="rocket">

                </div>
                 <a><button class="btn-success btn" style="margin-top: 20px;">Descargar Codigo</button></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>';

      }

      include "reportarextravio.php";
      include "daradopcion.php";
      include "modificarmascota.php";
      // <button class="btn-success btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalModificarMascota">Modificar Datos</button>

       ?>
```

EN  <?php
// consulta a la base de mascotas

```
      // sigue sin lograrse pero no da error, pero no muestra datos ver como se pude muestra o usar el atributo WHILE

      include "config/config.php";

      $usuario = $_SESSION['username'];
      
      $sqlMascotas = "SELECT * FROM mascotas m INNER JOIN propietarios p ON p.pemail = '$usuario' AND p.idpropietarios = m.idpropietario";
      $resultadoMascotas = $conexion->query($sqlMascotas);
      while ($row2 = $resultadoMascotas->fetch_assoc()){

       
      
      echo '<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <p class="mb-1 pt-2 text-bold">Codigo: KR'.$row2['idmascota'].'</p>
                <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">'.$row2['mnombre'].'</h5>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Fecha de Nacimiento: </strong> '.$row2['mnacimiento'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Salud: </strong>'.$row2['msalud'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Habitos: </strong>'.$row2['mhabitos'].'</p>
                <p class="mb-5"><strong>Descripcion: </strong>'.$row2['mdescripcion'].'</p>
                <button class="btn-danger btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalExtravio">Reportar Extraviado</button>
                <button class="btn-success btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalAdopcion">Dar en Adopción</button>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 ms-auto text-center mt-5 mt-lg-0">
              <div class="bg-gradient-primary border-radius-lg h-100">
                <img src="v1/assets/img/shapes/waves-white.svg" class="position-absolute h-100 w-50 top-0 d-lg-block d-none" alt="waves">
                <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <img class="h-100 w-75 position-relative z-index-2 pt-4" src="images/'.$row2['mimagen'].'" alt="rocket">
                </div>
                
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 ms-auto text-center mt-5 mt-lg-0">
              <div class="bg-gradient-primary border-radius-lg h-100">
                <img src="v1/assets/img/shapes/waves-white.svg" class="position-absolute h-100 w-50 top-0 d-lg-block d-none" alt="waves">
                <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <img class="w-60 position-relative z-index-2 pt-4" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=https://rumam.com.mx/app/perfil.php?id='.$row2['idmascota'].'&chld=H" style="width=300px !important;"" alt="rocket">

                </div>
                 <a><button class="btn-success btn" style="margin-top: 20px;">Descargar Codigo</button></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><br>';

      }

      include "reportarextravio.php";
      include "daradopcion.php";
      include "modificarmascota.php";
      // <button class="btn-success btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalModificarMascota">Modificar Datos</button>

       ?>
```

En la primera version si doy clic en el boton de una fila por ejemplo modificar, me abre el ID que corresponde a esa fila, en la version 2 cualquier boton dentro me hable el mismo ID

Comment: Si el problema es con un botón en particular nos ayuda que quites la paja, es decir, los elementos que no se relacionan al problema para crear un [EMCV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Si observas en la primer versión que funciona, al botón editar tiene controlador de eventos **onClick**, donde le pasa parámetros **id_mascotas, rasgos etc**, que ejecuta una función enviándole esos parámetros, en las otras versiones el mismo botón no tiene nada de eso.